# Is there a way to update a partial refund for an event registration and associated contribution?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

On 4.7.15

Tried to update a contribution record from Pending Refund to Completed (not integrated with accounting software)

Got "Cannot change contribution status from Pending refund to Completed" message

Customer registered on-line (we use Drupal) but made a selection error that requires a small refund.  I was able to change selections from within Civi, and prices updated correctly. Now that the refund has been processed through Authorize.net, I want to update the Contribution record.

Comment: Are you able to accept your own answer so this can be closed off

Comment: I was hoping that someone would either confirm or deny that this was the best way to handle this situation, but yes, this can be closed off, although I don't know how that happens.  Is that something I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Hi Diane - you are welcome to leave it longer but since no one else has responded yet it may be unlikely to gather more comments. You should be able to 'Accept' your own answer - unless you don't have enough 'reputation' yet to do so. Also worth knowing that there are more / other eyes watching at eg https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/user-support if you find you don't get support here. hope that helps.

Comment: i mentioned your ticket in that channel - seems to have given you another option. hope that helps

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to Accept - but we are currently testing the Line Item Edit extension.

Comment: let me go find some of your other questions to up your Reputation

Comment: hopefully that helps - looks like some of those questions also deserve some acknowledgement from you - helps keep the volunteers who support this service enthuised ;-)

Comment: Got it - still learning the ropes, and appreciate the help and guidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing the [Line Item Edit](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.lineitemedit) extension, then edit the line item.

Comment: Now that we finally updated to 5. something, we stumbled across this and are testing it - good to have validation we are moving in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered how to record a partial refund on registrations entered on-line as multiple registrations for the same organization.

Scenario:
Secretary registered 5 people for full conference passes.  Subsequently learned that 4 of them should have been 1-day passes.  It happens that the record that the payment info is associated with is not one of the ones being changed.

What I did:
I edited the four incorrect registrations clicking **Change Selections**, applying the correct discount code, making the correct selections, and clicking **Save**.  All the **Participant Status** fields were changed by CiviCRM to *Pending Refund*.  I did not click **Record Refund**, but observed that the **Fees** area was adjusting the total fees and indicating the difference from the Total Paid in the Balance column and the Status of the Contribution record for the payment had changed to *Pending Refund*.  When I completed all the edits, I went to the event record for the payer, and clicked **Record Refund** and completed the **New Refund** form. It showed the correct Refund Due.  I added in a *Fee Amount* because we add a processing fee for refunds.  The *Net Amount* calculated correctly. All **Participant Status** fields were  automatically updated to *Registered* and the status of the **Contribution** record for the registrations was updated to *Completed*, all the selection changes were recorded there, and the total fee was adjusted correctly. The only thing I don't see in the completed contribution and registration records is the actual refund amount, so I would record that in the contribution note field.